# FBX Export Plugin does not export animation layers

Tags: export, 3d, animation, 3ds-max

I'm trying to export a object with animation layers to a ascii fbx using 3ds Max (2012, 2014 or 2015).

The thing is that while Maya exports the animation layers, the 3dsMax exports the layer data, but not the animation curves on the layers, the result is animation lost.

Any thoughts on this?

Comment: This is a highly inapropriate place for this question. What can i say what you see is what you get, you can offcourse choose to write your own data.

Comment: I don't use 3ds or Maya but maybe this can help (I guess you already tried everything but sometimes little details can give some extra clues): http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/53457/why-does-exporting-to-fbx-in-3dmax-loses-simulated-animation, http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/58494/how-do-i-export-physique-animations-without-breaking-them?rq=1, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21481976/animated-model-from-3ds-max-doesnt-perfom-animation. You can also try posting this question on these 2 other Stacks (Overflow and GameDev)

Comment: thanks, where would it be appropiate to post 3ds Max questions?

Comment: The problems reported in those questions are not related.

Comment: @diego.martinez: *where would it be appropiate to post 3ds Max questions?* – [3D Graphics](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/86368/3d-graphics) once it gathered enough support.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is regarding 3D modeling.  Please commit to the [site proposal for 3D Graphics](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/86368/3d-graphics)

Answer (score 0):

In the FBX export options, you need to make sure `Bake Animations` is checked.

Sources: 
http://forums.cgsociety.org/archive/index.php?t-987766.html
http://markj3d.blogspot.co.uk/search/label/FBX

Comment: baking the animation results on the loss of the animation layers.